# How to change JAX-RS Bean parameter name on Bean Validation

Tags: java, jax-rs, bean-validation

I have the following REST service that receives a POJO/Bean as a parameter but it's name in the Bean Validation JSON response is presented as `arg0`.

How can I give it a custom name like "request"?

### REST Service

```
@Path("/service")
public class MyRequestResource {

    @POST
    public void post(@Valid MyRequest request) {
        /* do stuff here */
    }

}
```

### The POJO/Bean (`@BeanParam` if you will)

```
public class MyRequest {

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate date;

}
```

### Bean Validation response

As we can see the response JSON is returning **"arg0"** as the name of the bean param. How can I change the name for something custom like "request"?

```
{
    "exception": null,
    "fieldViolations": [],
    "propertyViolations": [],
    "classViolations": [],
    "parameterViolations": [
        {
            "constraintType": "PARAMETER",
            "path": "post.arg0.date",
            "message": "may not be null",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "returnValueViolations": []
}
```

Comment: In your ide settings, there should be an option to retain parameter names or metadata or something like that. Do you use eclipse?

Comment: @vikarjramun this is at runtime... your comment makes no sense

Comment: @BonanzaOne, it actually does make sense, parameter names metadata is preserved at runtime with correct flags. That said, try adding a like a `@FormParam("request")` annotation, maybe?

Comment: @BonanzaOne The reason I&#39;m saying this is because when you compile into class files, sometimes you lose parameter and variable names. Thus when they are accessed by reflection, you can&#39;t get their original names, and instead get arg0 or arg1... Although if you use maven or such, I have no idea how to go about keeping parameter names

Comment: If you use maven: `<plugin>  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  <version>3.1</version>  <configuration>   <source>1.8</source>   <target>1.8</target>         <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>  </configuration> </plugin>`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it gives me an error: `RESTEASY003875: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.FormParam("request")`

Comment: @vikarjramun the Maven parameter didn't work. For JAX-WS SOAP Web Services there is the `@WebParam` that does that, I am looking for something similar for JAX-RS.

Comment: @BonanzaOne look at the question Georg Henkel marked as duplicate. There is apparently a bit more to do before BeanValidation realizes that it has names available.

Comment: @vikarjramun I see. In fact the question is a duplicate, but too much work just for that. I would expect something simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @BonanzaOne To be honest, if you already have a validation.xml, it's not that much work that you should skip doing it. If I were you, I would implement that solution